# Наследование xml комментариев в c#

Tags: c#

Есть ли в **c#** возможность **наследовать xml комментарии**? Например, если я определил поле/метод в базовом классе и использую в потомке, его смысл не меняется - однако приходится вводить заново комментарий - иначе он не будет виден в IntelliSense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В случае интерфейсов `Visual Studio 2010` показывает `xml-комментарий` из него, если у реализаций интерфейса этот комментарий отсутствует. Предполагаю, что тоже самое должно происходить и в случае некоторого базового класса.

*А вообще, для автоматизации копирования `xml-комментариев` и прочих вещей хорошо подходит [`Ghostdoc.`](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx)*